# Quantify relative position of coordinates - python

Tags: python, pandas, vector

I have a df of coordinates representing points at various timescales. I want to calculate the average these points in relation to each other.

To achieve this, I'm aiming to calculate the space between each point and the rest of the points. I'm then hoping to average these points.

The following calculates the distance between each pair of points.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],             
        'id' : ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'],                 
        'X' : [1.0,3.0,2.0,2.0,4.0,3.0,3.0,5.0,4.0],
        'Y' : [1.0,1.0,0.5,2.0,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.0,3.0],
    })

ids = list(df['id'])

# get the points
points = df[["X", "Y"]].values

# calculate distance of each point from every other point.
# row i contains contains distances for point i. 
# distances[i, j] contains distance of point i from point j.
distances = distance.cdist(points, points, "euclidean")
distances = distances.flatten()

# get the start and end points
cartesian = list(itertools.product(ids, ids))

data = dict(
            start_region = [x[0] for x in cartesian],
            end_region = [x[1] for x in cartesian],
            distance = distances
        )

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

All I really need to output is:

```
   Time start_point end_point    X    Y
0     1           A         B  2.0  0.0
1     1           A         C  1.0 -0.5
2     1           B         C -1.0 -0.5
3     2           A         B  2.0  0.0
4     2           A         C  1.0  0.5
5     2           B         C -1.0  0.5
6     3           A         B  2.0  0.0
7     3           A         C  1.0  0.0
8     3           B         C -1.0  0.0
```

[image]

So the average position of these points in relation to each other would be the green coordinates.

But if I average the dataset above it displays:

[image]

I understand how this occurs. It's not referencing the other points.

Comment: Shouldn't the averaged vector always be zero?

Comment: Apologies @hilberts_drinking_problem. I've include greater context. Does it make more sense?

Comment: can you supply what the output would look like?

Comment: @Kenan, supplied

Comment: shouldn't there be a direction col in your result df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my take on it

```
import itertools

def relative_dist(gp):
     combs = list(itertools.combinations(gp.index, 2))
     df_gp = pd.concat([gp.loc[tup,:].diff() for tup in combs], keys=combs).dropna()

     return df_gp

df_dist = (df.set_index('id').groupby('Time')[['X','Y']].apply(relative_dist)
             .droplevel('id').rename_axis(['Time','start_point','end_point'])
             .reset_index())

Out[341]:
   Time start_point end_point    X    Y
0     1           A         B  2.0  0.0
1     1           A         C  1.0 -0.5
2     1           B         C -1.0 -0.5
3     2           A         B  2.0  0.0
4     2           A         C  1.0  0.5
5     2           B         C -1.0  0.5
6     3           A         B  2.0  0.0
7     3           A         C  1.0  0.0
8     3           B         C -1.0  0.0

df_avg = df_dist.groupby(['start_point','end_point'], as_index=False)[['X','Y']].mean()

Out[347]:
  start_point end_point    X    Y
0           A         B  2.0  0.0
1           A         C  1.0  0.0
2           B         C -1.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Andy L. I just have a quick question. I've included a figure displaying the moving points. The overall average position should is seen in the green coordinates. But when averaging the differences in vectors it's not referencing each point.

Comment: @jonboy: I am sorry I missed your message. Could you explain how you came up with all the values of green dots. Why their values are the same as values of `time=3`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion on how to visualise the relative positions of your points. I would want, for each timestamp, to plot an ellipse at position `(X_, Y_)` where:

- `X_` is the mean of your points X coordinates for that timestamp.
- `Y_` is the mean of your points X coordinates for that timestamp.
- the width of the ellipse equals the variance of your points X coordinates for that timestamp.
- the height of the ellipse equals the variance of your points Y coordinates for that timestamp.

In that way, in a glance and for each timestamp, you could read some very high level statistics about your coordinates distribution at that timestamp.

Here's some code to generate such a visualisation:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

# sample data with 4 timestamps
df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],             
        'id' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],                 
        'X' : [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,10,8,5,6],
        'Y' : [1,1,3,3,1,1,2,2,5,5,8,5,6,6,7,6],
       })

# for each timestamp, compute means and variances within all samples for that timestamp
means = df.groupby("Time")[["X", "Y"]].mean()
variances = df.groupby("Time")[["X", "Y"]].var()
df_ = pd.concat([means, variances], axis=1)
df_.columns = ["X_", "Y_", "var_X", "var_Y"]

# plot 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})
for row in df_.itertuples():
    ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(row.X_, row.Y_),  # position of the ellipse is (X,Y)
                width=row.var_X,  # width helps to get a grasp on X variance
                height=row.var_Y,  # height helps to get a grasp on Y variance
                angle=0)
    ax.add_artist(ellipse)
    ellipse.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
    ellipse.set_alpha(.4)
    plt.text(x=row.X_+0.2, y=row.Y_+0.2, s=f"t={row.Index}")  # just add timestamp legend


ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

plt.show()
```

Which would look like this:

[image]

What do you think? Another idea could be to do a GIF (in case the timestamps average collide too much).